# Add one to the last record from the DB. Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When adding new images, I want their position to start with the position of the last image + 1. I'm trying to do this, but an error comes out:

`Object of class App\Models\ProductImage could not be converted to number`.

How can I get the same result?

```
$product->productImage?$i = (ProductImage::latest('position')->first() + 1):$i = 1;
```

And can I do the same without using a Model?

Comment: change `first()` to `value('position')`

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Can I do the same without using the model class, but do it through eloquent relationships? I have `Products` linked to `ProductImag`e using `hasMany`. `ProductImages` can be accessed with `$product->productImage`.

Comment: If you want the largest position of all product images then I don't think you can, but for the latest of only related product positions it's just a matter of `$product->productImage()->latest('position')->value('position')` (note the `()` used in productImage here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a model event :

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures

In your ProductImage model

```php
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function (ProductImage $image) {
           $image->position = ProductImage::max('position') + 1;
            
        });
      }
```

using the max() function will return directly the max value without hydrating a Model

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Where should I write this? I do these actions inside the update function. Is this where I should write this function?

Comment: You have to put it in your ProductImage Model I have edit my answer to add a link to the documentation about events, don't forget to mark the answer as resolve if it helps you :)